# c++ classes and object reference

Tags: c++, class, object

I have the following c++ class

```
class Object 
{
    public:
        Object(parameters);
 ...
        const Object& method1(parameters) const;
        Object& method2(parameters) const;

    private:
}
```

the `method1` and `method2` implementations are:

```
const Object& Object::method1(parameters) const 
{
...
    Object* _obj = new Object;
...
    return *_obj;
}

Object& Object::method2(parameters) const 
{
...
    Object* _obj = new Object;
...
    return *_obj;
}
```

I have not defined a copy constructor. I know the functions return a reference to the allocated object and I still have to use "delete" to delete it.
I would like to avoid wasting memory and preserve information hiding.

Is this the right way to do this, or am I missing something?

Comment: please try to make your code readable by indenting when asking for help

Comment: Why not just return an `object` by value? What do you gain by returning a dynamically allocated instance (unless its lifetime is somehow managed by the `object` that creates it)?

Comment: Try to delete what is returned as see what the compiler says.

Comment: *"Is this the right way to do this"* - Definitely not. *"or am I missing something?"* - Yes, *C++* is not *Java*. *"I would like to avoid wasting memory and preserve information hiding."* - Then don't waste it with dynamic allocations.

Answer (score 4):

This is bad as nothing will ever delete the objects. They will be leaked.

Return smart pointers, a copy of the object without newing it, or the raw pointer.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the class, but returning a reference to
a dynamically allocated object is probably not a good idea.

- If the class has value semantics (supports copy and
  assignment), you should return an actual object; dynamic
  allocation of objects with value semantics should be avoided.
- If the class is a full fledged entity object, whose lifetime
  is managed by the application, you should probably return a raw
  pointer.
- If the returned object still needs more processing before it
  will be managed by the application, you should probably return
  `std::auto_ptr`, or if you can use C++11, `std::unique_ptr`; the
  caller will then release it once the application logic takes
  over, and if anything happens in the meantime, the object will
  automatically be destructed and the memory freed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++11, you can use `std::unique_ptr<object>` or `std::shared_ptr<object>` as return types (depending on the use-case). The object will then be destructed automatically as soon as the last smart pointer vanishes.

These classes are also available in boost (well, `std::unique_ptr` maps to `boost::scoped_ptr`), in case your compiler does not support C++11. You can also use `std::auto_ptr` if you need to, but it has been deprecated with C++11.

Comment: Returning by value could well be the best solution, although it is difficult to say without more information.

Comment: Yes, it may be or may be not. I assumed that the OP has a reason for allocating the objects on the heap.

Comment: It is almost never appropriate for a function which `new`s an object to return it with `std::shared_ptr`: once `shared_ptr` has taken over, you're stuck with it for the rest of the object lifetime (which is rarely appropriate).

Comment: And of course, if the object is copyable, he shouldn't return a pointer at all.  This is, or should be the default; about the only time you want to dynamically allocate something in C++ is because it is an entity object with identity, and generally a lifetime determined by the application logic.  (But even in strongly OO applications, such objects are a minority.)

Comment: Can you please clarify, what does it mean: "you're stuck with it for the rest of the object lifetime (which is rarely appropriate)"? returning a smart pointer is the only good way of returning a "big" object under RAII paradigm.

Comment: *"I assumed that the OP has a reason for allocating the objects on the heap."* - Never assume anything (at least not any knowledge about proper value semantics) from *Java* code like that.

Comment: @DarkWanderer: Returning `shared_ptr` forces the object to be managed by shared pointers for the rest of its lifetime, which is not always appropriate. Instead, you should usually return `unique_ptr` (or `auto_ptr`, if you're stuck in the past) to allow the caller to choose how to manage the object: either leaving it in the returned pointer, transferring it to a shared pointer, or releasing it to manage some other way. (Assuming that dynamic allocation is appropriate in the first place, of course. It usually isn't.)

Comment: @Mike Seymour: James Kanze's post reads as if he's opposing returning *any* smart pointers from a function, including unique_ptr. Also, the phrase "you're stuck with it for the rest of the object lifetime" is not clear to me - which object? The object lifetime is managed by the pointer, not the other way.

Comment: @DarkWanderer: That's not how I read James' comment; he was specifically referring to `shared_ptr`. "The object" is the dynamically allocated object being managed by the smart pointer. The objection to `shared_ptr` is that, once you start managing the object with a shared pointer, you have no choice but to carry on using shared pointers; and shared semantics are not always appropriate. `unique_ptr` gives you the option to release it and use whatever management scheme is most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

in this case you should use the return value as pointer `object* object::methodn(parameters) const` or implement copy constructor and then return not the reference but the copy of the object, because when you look at the declaration of `method1` or `method2` you can't even imagine that there is created a memory leak inside. Also if you're using C++11 you can use `rvalue reference` to ease up on memory using copy contructor[here's some info on C++11 rvalue references](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html)